# Wagtail, register settings singleton

Tags: python, wagtail

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseGenericSetting, register_setting

@register_setting
class Glossary(BaseGenericSetting)
    ...
```

Is it possible to restrict max number of instances that can be created? Maybe there is some easy way or only overwriting `save` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `BaseGenericSetting` works as standard - it ensures that only a single instance of the setting object is ever created. If you visit the settings area in the admin again once it has been created, it will allow you to edit the existing object, not create a new one.

This might only be enforced within the admin view rather than at the model level, though - if you need to work with settings objects in code, use `Glossary.load()` to retrieve the single instance. (This will create the instance if it doesn't already exist.)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm checking the admin area - and I can create another instance. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you go to Settings -> Glossary (assuming that's where you've placed the menu item)? On my project, that takes me directly to the edit view for the existing settings record, with a "Save" button - there is no option to add a new one.

Comment: It redirects me to standart view/add/delete page. How did you register your model using `modeladmin_register`?

Comment: I don't register it with modeladmin_register at all - the `@register_setting` line handles all the necessary setup for the admin backend.